# Specify object type of a returned array list dynamically

Tags: java, types, casting, arraylist

I have following class which takes an interface and execute some functions:

```
public class MSSQLHandler {

    IMSSQLStatement statement;

    public MSSQLHandler(IMSSQLStatement statement) {
        this.statement = statement;
    }

    public void invoke() throws SQLException {
        statement.executeStatement();
    }

    public List<?> getDataList() throws SQLException {
        return statement.getDataList();
    }
}
```

The interface is implemented by an abstract class:

```
public abstract class MSSQLStatement implements IMSSQLStatement {

    protected Connection conn = null;
    protected ResultSet rs = null;

    protected abstract String createStatement() throws SQLSyntaxErrorException;

    public MSSQLStatement(Connection conn) {    
       this.conn = conn;
    }

    public void executeStatement() throws SQLException {    
       Statement st = conn.createStatement();
       String sql = createStatement();
       if(sql != null) {
          rs = st.executeQuery(createStatement());
       } else {
          throw new SQLException("Method 'createStatement()' has to be implemented.");
       }
    }    
}
```

The class (or the interface) which is passed to the handler class extend the abstract class from above:

```
public class MSSQLTaskStatement extends MSSQLStatement {

    public MSSQLTaskStatement(Connection conn) {
    super(conn);
    }

    private String projectName = null;

    public void setProjectName(String projectName) {
    this.projectName = projectName;
    }

    protected String createStatement() throws SQLSyntaxErrorException {
      // Create SQL query
    }

    @Override
    public List<MyObjectData> getDataList() throws SQLException {
      // Wrap results into a data object and save it to an array list
      List<MyObjectData> l = new ArrayList<MyObjectData>()
      while(rs.next()) {
         MyObjectData o = new MyObjectData();
         o.setColumn1(rs.getString(1))
         l.add(o);
      }
      return l;
    }
}
```

The question is whether it is possible to pass the object type (`MyObjectData`) of the returned list of the overridden `getDataList()` method from the class `MSSQLTaskStatement` to the handler class `public List<?> getDataList() throws SQLException` method ?

Best Regards,
Sandro

Comment: Which classes/interfaces of these can you change? All of them?

Comment: Yes. Maybe I use a bad design but in general it is working good so far. I only want to get rid of the necessary cast when invoking the getDataList() method of the handler class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a type parameter `<T>` or `<T extends ObjectDataBaseClass>` to `IMSSQLStatement` and `MSSQLStatement`, change the method getDataList in IMSSQLStatement to `List<T> getDataList()` and use `public class MSSQLTaskStatement extends MSSQLStatement<MyObjectData>`.

Then, if your `MSSQLHandler` has a field `IMSSQLStatement<MyObjectData> statement`, its own `getDataList()` can type-safely return a `List<MyObjectData>` (or you can make `MSSQLHandler` generic too, if you want to use it with statements that do not build on `MyObjectData`).

Comment: Thanks! Just make my MSSQLHandler class also generic with MSSQLHandler<T> and it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer Spring's [JdbcTemplate](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html) class. There is required functionality that you can use even without using Spring at all. Or you can just use it as a helpful guide to build your own persistent layer implementation.