# How to force putting a object into a handler class

Tags: java, interface, handler

I already post some relevant code in this question:
[Specify object type of a returned array list dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15270133/specify-object-type-of-a-returned-array-list-dynamically)

Now my question is a little bit more specific.

In fact I am using the following "handler" class to invoke methods of classes which implement the interface `IMSSQLStatement`:

```
public class MSSQLHandler {

    IMSSQLStatement statement;

    public MSSQLHandler(IMSSQLStatement statement) {
        this.statement = statement;
    }

    public void invoke() throws SQLException {
        statement.executeStatement();
    }

    public List<?> getDataList() throws SQLException {
        return statement.getDataList();
    }
}
```

The question is now how to force me (or an developer which implements my interface) to put created objects of the implemented class to `MSSQLHandler`?

Maybe this is bad design but I did not find any information and use cases regarding my problem.

Comment: You can't...... since interfaces can't enforce anything, except method signature implementation.

Comment: Hmm, ok. Is it possible with other technologies? Maybe with an abstract class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use an abstract class with an explicit constructor, that is automatically called on all subclasses:

```
public abstract class IMSSQLStatement {

    protected IMSSQLHandler handler;

    public IMSSQLStatement() {
        handler = new IMSSQLHandler(this);
    }
}
```

---

Edit: (in reference to comment)

If you want that only the handler should be able to call the methods in `IMSSQLStatement`, both classes should be placed in the same package. Allow only *package-private* and subclass access, by giving the `protected` modifier. Although the methods could be called in the subclass itself, it would not be accessible outside, with the exception of the package.

This won't solve your problem completely. The other (real bogus) way around would be *reflection*.

To use reflection, you should write in your documentation the exact method signature the subclass should use (of course, don't define an abstract method in the superclass), giving it the ***private*** modifier. The handler should access these methods through reflection.

Refer some document, that describes how to use reflection. This is complicated, and beyond the scope of SO.

Comment: Okay, the handler class is now called when creating a object of implementing classes. But this is not really what I want. I still can execute methods of the implementing class "outside" the handler class. But I want that only the handler class is able to execute the methods.

Comment: Thanks! I already read something about reflection to solve this use case. I just have to make the private methods accessable and invoke it. However is this good practice? Is this used in some "offical" java library?

Comment: They are used quite often in Java Standard Classes, for instance serialization, LookAndFeel loading, and more. Read [here](http://uet.vnu.edu.vn/~chauttm/e-books/java/Effective.Java.2nd.Edition.May.2008.3000th.Release.pdf) (page 230) about the advantages and disadvantages about reflection